# Ionic InAppBrowser PDF iOS no back Button

Tags: javascript, ios, pdf, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I created an app in Visual Studio Code using Cordiva, Ionic and Angular. I can request some json files from my server and in this json is amongst other things a pdf-file in base64 format. to show the pdf i got the InAppBrowser plugin and to display the pdf i use this code:

Constructor:

```
constructor(public events: Events, public httpClient: HttpClient, private iab: InAppBrowser, 
    public userServiceProvider: UserServiceProvider, public deviceServiceProvider: DeviceServiceProvider) {
    super(events);
  }
```

and the specific call:

```
const browser = this.inAppBrowser.create('assets/pdf/web/viewer.html', '_blank', 'location=no,zoom=no,toolbar=no,fullscreen=yes,hidden=yes');
      let load: boolean = false;
      browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(event => {
        if (!load) {
          browser.executeScript({ code: "loadBase64Content('" + entity.pdfContent + "')" });
          load = true;
        }
        browser.show();
      });
```

the assets/pdf/web/viewer.html is: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/web/viewer.html

i added a small js snipped to convert the base64 content.

```
<script>
    function loadBase64Content(base64) {
      var u8_2 = new Uint8Array(atob(base64).split("").map(function (c) {
        return c.charCodeAt(0);
      }));
      PDFViewerApplication.open(u8_2)
    }
  </script>
```

the pdf is shown as wished.
In Android i can use the hardware back button to go back to my app but for iOS i need a software button to close the browser or i am stuck in the pdf viewer and have to close the app. i tried it with a normal button with onclick="close()" - but this did not work - thats the reason i think i need to close the browser itself - but how can i make a function call from the view.html to my parent page to call close/hide on the browser instance.

Comment: For iOS, try by swiping back to the previous view is it going back with that?

Comment: I think you can display a toolbar using toolbar=yes in create method of in app browser

Comment: the solution was so near.. i just have to call the create method with the parameter toolbar=yes. the toolbar is für ios only and contains a done button which can be changed in text and color.